# Resurrecting std::auto_ptr in GCC when compiling with -std=c++17

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, auto-ptr

Is there a macro or compiler flag that would let me keep using `auto_ptr` in GCC 7/8 with `-std=c++17`? I have easily found the corresponding macro for clang and MSVC, but my Google-fu is not good enough to find the solution for GCC.

I don't want to use `-fpermissive` (it would let me accidentally do too much stuff I shouldn't be able to do), need something more specific.

P. S. I'm not using `auto_ptr`, but I have an important 3rd-party library that does.

Comment: What errors are you getting? I only see a warning with GCC 8.1.

Comment: And it [specifically documents](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017) that it hasn't been removed, that it's been kept around for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @hvd: ugh, thanks. That's what I get for asking before trying. I was compiling on Mac and though I'd rather solve the problem with a single commit for all platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can compile with `-Wno-deprecated-declarations` to make GCC (also works with clang) ignore warnings about deprecated classes.

You might want to only use this flag for your third party library as it's still a good warning for code that's under your control.